# How to place Bootstrap form inputs closer to eachother?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a form using Bootstrap in which I need to place many inputs on one line like if it where a Spreadsheet. So using the regular Bootstrap grid system I did this (snippet):

```
<div class="col-sm-1">
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea placeholder="Description" class="form-control" rows="1" required></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1">
    <input placeholder="Remaining contract term" class="form-control" type="text">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon">€</div>
            <input placeholder="Contract rental" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
etc.
```

which results in:

[image]

Obviously that looks horrible. For this specific form I need to place the inputs closer to eachother so that they (almost) touch eachother.

Does anybody know how I can style this better? All tips are welcome!

Comment: in bootstrap there is left and right padding `15px` so set custom css selector and reduce the padding to `1px` http://jsfiddle.net/0m8j5c7x/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the padding on the col-sm-* with a class like this

```
    .inputItem {
          padding-left: 2px;
          padding-right: 2px;
    }
```

Comment: Is the `!important;` needed?

Comment: I don't believe it is needed, I just used it to ensure that it was overwritten, just removed them and checked it and there was no problem, I will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful.

You can adjust your column padding by media queries in the event you want the form to stack on smaller devices so the padding returns to normal.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  form .form-gutter >[class*='col-'] {
    padding-right: 1px;
    padding-left: 1px;
  }
}
form .form-control,
form .input-group-addon {
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form class="form">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Form </h1>

    <div class="row form-gutter">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input placeholder="Contract rental" class="form-control" type="text">
            <div class="input-group-addon">€</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">Some</label>
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">Thing</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input placeholder="Remaining contract term" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input placeholder="Remaining contract term" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon">€</div>
            <input placeholder="Contract rental" class="form-control" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon">€</div>
            <input placeholder="Contract rental" class="form-control" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```